# Amazon QuickSight - Filter by now()

Tags: amazon-quicksight

i'm trying to run a very simple query that uses the now() function, i don't get a useful error message, all what i get is "unknown error". here is the query

```
select transaction_date 
from trans  
where transaction_date  <= now()
```

the transaction_date is already a date field, i tried to do some casting but it didn't work too

```
select transaction_date 
from trans  
where date(transaction_date)  <= date(now())
```

the datasource is a redshift cluster

Answer (score 0):

so i figured out what is wrong here, i run the query directly on redshift cluster , and i got this error message "ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables." i wish that quicksight just passed the same error message to me instead of showing "Unknown Error" , i replaced now() with GETDATE() and it worked perfectly !